# UIWebView not opening a link

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, nsstring, nsurl, nslog

```
for(int i=0; i<arrString.count;i++){
if([[arrString objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:@"www."].location != NSNotFound)
    link = [arrString objectAtIndex:i];
}


NSString *url = (@"THIS IS WHERE HTTP:// would Be!%@", link);
    NSLog(@"THIS IS WHERE HTTP:// would Be!%@", url);
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[_webView1 loadRequest:nsrequest];
```

When I use NSLog:

```
NSLog(@"THIS IS WHERE HTTP:// would Be!, url);
```

It logs the correct URL that begins with `http://.` However, when I set the string URL equal to `http://"link"`, it returns nothing. Any help is much appreciated.

(Stack Overflow is not letting me put the real HTTP:// followed by an %@.)

Comment: try put url in comment.

Comment: Please can you be more specific. What exactly "returns nothing"?

Comment: Also I suggest you rewrite your first chunk of code to use fast enumeration; much clearer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may need to use `stringWithFormat:`

```
NSString *domainName = @"aol.com";
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.%@", domainName];
```